# Is possible to add NUMBER value return in Js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Javascript. In success function, I am getting some results and storing in var say "baldet" in JS-CODE.

example:

```
success: function (result) {
        baldet = result;

        console.log(baldet[0].cleavebalance);

        if (openmon == 1){
        $("#clvbalance").val(baldet[0].cleavebalance);
    }
    }
```

from **baldet[0].cleavebalance** I am getting 2. My condition is if openmon == 1 then I want to add number 1 in it.

**NOTE: add means SUM, not CONCAT()**

So that i could get, 2 (from "baldet[0].cleavebalance" + 1 (number i want to add)) i.e. 2 + 1 = 3.

and show in $("#clvbalance").val("3"); // **value 3 is after getting SUM RESULT**

Currently, I am getting "21" instead of "3"

I hope I made my query clear. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @CertainPerformance. Yes you got it. Please help.

Comment: use [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) for convert string to number . `parseFloat(baldet[0].cleavebalance)+1`

Comment: @prasanth thanks for reply, I am very new to it I am not getting exactly what you say.

Comment: Check my answer below to have a better understanding

Comment: @OTPGenerator refer the already answer question .You could learn better difference between string and number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse from string to number like below

```js
console.log("2" + 1); // dose not parse

console.log(parseInt("2") + 1)
```